# Trimming one part if equal to another part?

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression, perl

I use an e-mail quote attribution string like this:

```
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (Example Dot Org):
```

where `info@example.org` is the sender's e-mail address and `Example Dot Org` is the sender's real name.

When no real name is provided (or even sometimes when one is), the two are identical, and I end up with an attribution string like this:

```
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (info@example.org):
```

If (and only if) this is the case, I want to remove the `(info@example.org)` part, leaving me with only:

```
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org:
```

I already have a shell script which calls out to Perl to massage the e-mail before feeding it to my editor, and am thinking I could simply add some code to that to massage the attribution line as well. The solution could be done in Perl, awk, sed, or something else (though preferably not something *too* exotic).

I do know that the attribution line is the first non-blank line following the first blank line of the input, and I don't mind hardcoding against my preferred attribution line format. Simply deleting the part in paranthesises is trivial, but **how to do it only when it is equal to what precedes it?** Preferably without risking altering anything else in the email (text file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just substitute the substring containing the two occurrences of the address with the substring's first half, containing only one address:

```
bash-4.2$ echo '
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (Example Dot Org):
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (info@example.org):
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org:
' | sed -r 's/(, from (\S+)) \(\2\)/\1/'

On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (Example Dot Org):
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org:
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org:
```

Comment: I ended up refining this to `sed -r 's/^(On [0-3][0-9] [A-Z][a-z][a-z] [12][0-9]{3} [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [+-][0-9]{4})(, from (\S+)) \(\3\):$/\1\2:/'`, which is a fair bit more restrictive in what it matches, but also more closely matches my usage. Your example was great as a starting point. Many thanks, and an upvote for posterity. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print "($F[07]):" eq "$F[8]" ? "@F[0..7]:" : "@F"'
```

This Perl one liner will split the string on spaces, so following string will be split into 9 parts:

```
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org (info@example.org):
```

It will compare part8 (e-mail address) with part9 (senders name) and if they are same then part8 will be removed. leaving you with:

```
On dd mmm yyyy hh:mm +hhmm, from info@example.org:
```